# Interating through Array with if-else statements (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I'm fairly new to Swift and this has got me stumped. I have :

```
for values in input {
    if num >= 80 {
        message = "hot!"
    }
    else if num >= 60 && num < 80 {
        message = "warm!"
    }
    else if  num >= 40 && num < 60 {
        message = "cool!"
    }
    else if num <= 40 {
        message = "cold!"
    }
    print("The temperature \(values) is \(message)")
}
```

And this is printing as

```
"Please enter a temperature 65"
"Please enter a temperature 1"
"Please enter a temperature 100"
"Please enter a temperature 56"
"Please enter a temperature 46"
"The temperature 65 is warm!"
"The temperature 1 is warm!"
"The temperature 100 is warm!"
"The temperature 56 is warm!"
"The temperature 46 is warm!"
```

As you can see it's not going one by one but instead naming each element of array the same. What am I doing wrong here? I'm using readLine() for the array elements.

Comment: please make your code a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that goes straight to the point (e.g. bug) and trim everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning Swift, you need to learn a couple conventions:

1. Collection types (array, set, dictionary, etc.) should be named using plural. For example, it should be `inputs` instead of `input`.
2. When you iterate through the array, the iterator should be named in singular, like `value` instead of `values`.
3. You are comparing the wrong variable. It should be `value` instead of `num`

Other than that, you can write your code more concisely using `switch`:

```
for value in inputs {
    var message = ""

    switch value {
    case 80...:             // equivalent to: if 80 <= num
        message = "hot!"
    case 60..<80:           // equivalent to: if 60 <= num && num < 80
        message = "warm!"
    case 40..<60:           // equivalent to: if 40 <= num && num < 60
        message = "cool"
    case ..<40:             // equivalent to: if num < 40
        message = "cold"
    default:
        message = ""        // this is actually not reachable since the cases above cover
                            // all possible scenarios. But Swift require switch statement
                            // to be exhaustive and it doesn't go that deep to prove that
                            // we already had everything covered. This is to silence the
                            // compiler.
    }
    print("The temperature \(value) is \(message)")
}
```

Comment: no need to declare message a var `let message: String` as long as you initialize it in all cases including the default as you are already doing it now.

Comment: Doing this led to lots of errors saying - Expression pattern of type 'CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>' cannot match values of type 'String''

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you are comparing num against your temp range and not the values variable. So i believe that the value of num has been defined outside of the array itself and never mutated.

With that being said I believe a switch statement would better suit ur needs and would be much cleaner in this case.

Just don’t forget to compare the values and not the num variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
for value in input {
    if value >= 80 {
        message = "hot!"
    }
    else if value >= 60 && value < 80 {
        message = "warm!"
    }
    else if value >= 40 && value < 60 {
        message = "cool!"
    }
    else if value <= 40 {
        message = "cold!"
    }
    print("The temperature \(value) is \(message)")
}
```

Comment: Getting error - Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'